# Resolving git merge conflict issue on every commit

Tags: git

I created a branch `dev` and from that branch a second branch called `test`.

The commit history for the two branches looks as follows: I am making changes to on `dev` that from time to time are merged via PR to `test` .

Problem: Every time I raise a PR from `dev` to `test` I get a merge conflict and the the commit list in the PR shows the entire list from dev to be merged into test. I guess the right way to setup the branches would have been to start with `test` and branch off from that but is there a way to fix that with the existing branches?

```
test ---o----------------o-
       /                /
dev  -o-------o----o---o---
```

Comment: Are you squash-merging?

Answer (score 0):

It's likely that you're making changes to the same lines in both branches, which results in conflicts. Based on your description, it appears your challenge lies in maintaining a branch over an extended period. You create a branch for a new feature, and then you want to add another new feature but subsequently need to update it with changes from the source code, leading to recurring conflicts. To streamline this, keep your Merge/Pull request open for a single specific purpose. Once that purpose is achieved, merge it and create a new branch for subsequent tasks. Typically, you should only need to resolve conflicts once when merging your current branch with the source branch.